# Confused on the fringe cases of Code Forces question Ski Resort

Tags: c++, arrays, logic

I was solving this problem:
https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1840/C

The code I wrote for this worked for all the example inputs, but when I submit it on Code forces, it says the code failed on test 6...

I don't know which particular edge case I'm missing with my code, which is what I want to find out.

To explain example, let input be 10,15,0,2,3,20,3
let min num of consecutive days be 2
let maximum temperature for good day be 12 degrees

[image: This is the logic of the code]

This is the code:

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<string>
    using namespace std;

    int main(){

        int t;
        cin>>t;

        for(int i=0; i<t; i++){
            int n, k, q;
            cin>>n>>k>>q;
            int size=10000;  // creating a large array where I'll be storing the 'consecutive good day' streaks
            int grp[size]={0};
            int count=0;
            for(int j=0; j<n; j++){        //filling the array
                int num;
                cin>>num;
                if(num>q){                  
                    count++;
                }else{
                    grp[count]++;
                }
            }

            int ans=0;
            for(int j=0; j<size; j++){   //for each good day streak, calculating total possible alternatives and adding to sum
                int l = grp[j]-k+1;        
                if(l<1){continue;}        
                ans+=l*(l+1)/2;
            }
            cout<<ans<<endl;
            
        }


        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Your second loop should only run through `j <= count`, not `j < size`, but I don't think that affects the result.  However, since `n` can run up to 20,000, you could construct a pathological case that overflowed your array.  Maybe use `if( num > q && grp[count] )` so you don't have a bunch of zeros?

Comment: Try making a test case with `1`, `12000 3 5`, and then have 11997 x '9' and 3 x  '0'.  The answer should be 1, but you will come up with 0.

Comment: I found solution. It was that ans had to be long long int.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion doesn't quite work; it needs to be a nested condition:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;

    for(int i=0; i<t; i++){
        int n, k, q;
        cin>>n>>k>>q;
        int size=10000;
        int grp[size]={0};
        int count=0;
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
            int num;
            cin>>num;
            if(num>q){
                if( grp[count] ){
                    count++;
                }
            }else{
                grp[count]++;
            }
        }

        int ans=0;
        for(int j=0; j<size; j++){   //for each good day streak, calculating total possible alternatives and adding to sum
            int l = grp[j]-k+1;
            if(l<1){continue;}
            ans+=l*(l+1)/2;
        }
        cout<<ans<<endl;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

This works with the pathological case I described above.

Comment: Although Even this code doesn't work, and the problem still persists

Comment: Don't they give you the test case that fails?

Comment: I'm new, so I didn't know. But after more digging around I found out that the test case was a huge one, so the ans variable had to be long long int. Thank you anyways @Tim Roberts